# App Store In-App Subscription Pricing - Apple and Google

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, in-app-subscription

I am working on launching my first app ever. Yes, super exciting, but also terrifying LOL.

I am working with an app dev company that has been extremely helpful thus far, but when it comes to the pricing structure I am looking to implement, they say that it cannot be done.

I find this hard to believe, as it seems like anything is possible, however, I have not the first clue how to operate the backend of Apple App Store and Google Play Store in regards to pricing and subscriptions we have available for in-app purchases.

I am not looking to do this behind my dev teams back whatsoever, but am looking for any advice y'all can provide in regards to what I am looking to do so I can share it with them and we can make it happen together!

I am launching an app for employers who are doctors to find associate doctors for their offices.

Therefore the pricing I am attempting to construct in the Apple App Store and Google Play Store is the following:

The app is free on each store. When the Employer downloads the app > creates an account > hits a paywall prior to entering. I am looking to charge the employer a one-time upfront higher fee and then a recurring smaller fee to help with retention rates and continue to have them stay and engage in our community.

So, with example numbers I am looking to charge an employer at that payment portal say a $299 initial one-time fee for their first month with us on the app and then say a $49/month auto-recurring fee after that, month 2 and beyond.

How would you go about setting something like this up in each respective Store (Apple and Google)?

I am genuinely curious if it is at all possible, because I spoke with Apple and Google this morning via phone and email and they said it was possible but didn't provide great direction in regards to actually setting it up and what that would entail for each of their Stores.

Thanks in advance!

Kindly,
John

Comment: Not sure about Google, but Apple want apps (if they are free to purchase) to have working functionality, without IAP or subscriptions. "creates an account > hits a paywall prior to entering"... doesn't sound good.

Comment: Disney+ and many entertainment apps are doing this.